# Field and text in the same line

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have this in contact form 7 in wordpress form:

```
Your Name (required)
[text* your-name size:30 maxlength:60]

Your Email (required)
[email* your-email "yourmail@example.com"]

Your Message
[textarea your-message]
default value for a textarea
can be multi-line
like this
[/textarea]

[submit "Send"]
```

How is it possible to have the field and the title in the same line? Example, the field "Your Name (required)" and the field "text your-name..."  on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!!

You can add your custom div classes here and style theme in your themes style.css with the class names.

```
<div class="formclasses">
<div class="yourname">Your Name (required) </div>
<div class="yournameinput">[text* your-name size:30 maxlength:60]</div>
</div>
```

** Example CSS :**

```
.formclasses {
width:100%;
}
.yourname{
float:left;
}
.yournameinput{
float:left;
}
```